# How to make a textBox value to a name of array variable?

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, matrix, textbox, call

I have some public array variables:

```
double[,] matrikkookurensisub1_0 = new double[256, 256]; 
double[,] matrikkookurensisub1_45 = new double[256, 256]; 
double[,] matrikkookurensisub1_90 = new double[256, 256]; 
double[,] matrikkookurensisub1_135 = new double[256, 256];
```

I want to insert a `textBox` value to being name of my public array variable, this is my code in a buttonClick:

```
        //mks1_0 FIX!                
        int a = 0, b = 45, c = 90, d = 135;            
        textBox33.Text = textBox33.Text + a;
        for (int y = 0; y < ukuran1; y++) //*pada catatan langkah 3.
            for (int x = 0; x < ukuran1; x++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < 63; i++) 
                    {                            
                        if (dataSubcitra1[i, j] == x && dataSubcitra1[i + 1, j] == y)
                        {
                            matrikkookurensisub1_0[x, y]++;
                        }
                    }
            }
```

My default value of `textBox33` is `matrikkookurensisub1_`, but after `textBox33.Text = textBox33.Text + a;` now my `textBox33` is `matrikkookurensisub1_0`.

Look at my if statement :

```
if (dataSubcitra1[i, j] == x && dataSubcitra1[i + 1, j] == y)
{
     matrikkookurensisub1_0[x, y]++;
}
```

I want to make a textBox33 value to call this => "matrikkookurensisub1_0".

Comment: Sounds like you want to write `"matrikkookurensisub1_0"` in `textBox33` but you do that already. I respect that English might not be your first language but please take another look at the question and see if you can't clear it up for us.

Comment: i'm sorry sir, but i want is call my variable name with textbox value (textbox.text).. example i've variable public= matrix_0, matrix_45. first my textbox.text = "matrix_". in other event, textbox.text = textbox.text + a; (where int a=0;) now textbox.text = "matrix_0".. how can i call my variable with textbox.text, example textbox.text[x,y]=1; <= (it's mean matrix_0[x,y]=1; but by textbox.text call)

Comment: You want to pick which variable to use by entering the name of the variable in `textBox33`?

Comment: `double[,] matrikkookurensisub1_0 = new double[256, 256];` this one sir

Comment: I'll take that as a yes. I can't help you right now but I'll make you a solution when I get some time over.